# Extract common objects from an arraylist

Tags: arraylist

I have a list like shown below. Assume it has 16 Container objects in it. Each Container object is a simple bean, with fields like age, weight, height, etc. How can I create a sub-list that contains common 'Container' objects if a 'Container' object is considered equal if the weight and height are equal?

```
List<Container> containers = new ArrayList<Container>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks John Smith for giving direction on this question. I used the iterator instead and was able to make a nice solution to what I was looking for. below is the solution. Note that .equals is overriden for the Containers comparison. The technique I used will take the master list and create a sub-list while removing elements from the parent list at the same time. The solution can be called recursivly until you convert the master list into a subset of lists.

```
public List<Container> extractCommonSubList(
        List<Container> masterContainerList) {

    List<Container> subList = new ArrayList<Container>();
    ListIterator<Container> iterator = masterContainerList.listIterator();

    // get first item from master list and remove from master list
    Container firstContainer = iterator.next();
    iterator.remove();

    // Add first container to sublist
    subList.add(firstContainer);

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        Container container = iterator.next();

        // Search for matches
        if (firstContainer.equals(container)) {
            // containers are a match, continue searching for matches
            subList.add(container);
            iterator.remove();
            continue;
        } else {
            break;
        }

    }

    // return common list
    return subList;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "common" containers you mean duplicating ones, then this code might help you:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class CommonContainers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Container> containers = new ArrayList<Container>(16);
        for(int i=0; i<13; i++) {
            containers.add(new Container(i, i));
        }
        //add a few duplicating ones
        containers.add(new Container(1,1));
        containers.add(new Container(5,5));
        containers.add(new Container(6,6));

        List<Container> sublist = new ArrayList<Container>();
        for (Container c1 : containers) {
            for (Container c2 : containers) {
                if(c1 != c2 && c1.equals(c2)) {
                    sublist.add(c1);
                }
            }
        }

        for (Container c : sublist) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }

    private static class Container {
        private int weight;
        private int height;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Container[w=%d,h=%d]", weight, height);
        }

        public Container(int weight, int height) {
            this.weight = weight;
            this.height = height;
        }

        public int getWeight() {
            return weight;
        }

        public void setWeight(int weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
        }

        public int getHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        public void setHeight(int height) {
            this.height = height;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + height;
            result = prime * result + weight;
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Container other = (Container) obj;
            if (height != other.height)
                return false;
            if (weight != other.weight)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

If you mean something else or need clarification, please let me know.

Comment: Yep thats very similar to the code I have so far but the sublist elements are only considered equal if height is equal. Now I am getting a ConcurrentModificationException while trying to do containers.removeAll(subList); the main idea is to iterate the 'master list', create sublists, remove sublist from master list, rinse, wash, repeat until the entire master list is depleted of all elements and I have a sub set of lists that I can work with. Any thoughts on the Exception?

Comment: Well, if you're iterating over the list which you are removing elements from, this is where you are getting the exception, because you are changing its size (by deleting elements) while you're walking over it. Try using the list's iterator (containers.iterator()) and do removal through the iterator (it.remove()) to avoid the exception.